# Autocomplete returns an error on ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery Autocomplete on a text box, but it's not working.

Here is my script to get autocomplete list from database but it gives me error and alerts error message.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ContentPlaceHolderSearch_txt_Search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Service/AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionListName",
                data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Here Is my server code

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionListName(string prefixText, int count)
{
    List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
    GA_UsersTableAdapter uta = new GA_UsersTableAdapter();
    UserControllar.GA_UsersDataTable udt = uta.GetDataByNameAutoComplete(prefixText);
    foreach (DataRow row in udt.Rows)
    {
        items.Add(row["Full_Name"].ToString());
    }
    return items.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: `data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "' }"` looks very strange. Shouldn't it be `data: { prefixText: request.term }`?

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Where is it failing? have you tried setting breakpoints in chrome? What is the error message?

Comment: By the way, you didn't provide your related server-side code and error text.

Comment: Have you enabled this `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in web service, so that JS script can access this webservice via ajax call?

Comment: i've edited my post and added my server-side code

Comment: what is actual error message?

Comment: yes @Arindam Nayak i already did that

Comment: You don't send `count` in request.

Comment: error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);

it alerts fail and "Internal Server Error" for the errorThrown

Comment: @Regent i don't see where to add 'count'

Comment: Your webmethod is expecting a parameter named 'count' and you are not giving it to it. That may be the cause.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `GetCompletionListName(string prefixText, int count)` expects two params: `prefixText` and `count`. As `count` is more or less useless, you can delete it.

Comment: @Regent i deleted count, also try to pass a count parameter using my script...but the error still exists

Comment: Try setting a break point in your GetCompletionListName method and see if it fails somewhere there.

Comment: I know my method working as expected, because i used it with AjaxControleToolkit autocomplete extender and it was working,

Comment: actually no break points is hitting now

Comment: Google Chrome debugger show this error, does this has anything to do with my problem ?


POST http://localhost:1533/RMS/Service/AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionListProjects 500 (Internal Server Error) 

jquery-1.8.2.js:8430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just changed my service path in script from

```
url: "Service/AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionListName"
```

to

```
url: "../Service/AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionListName"
```

and it works now...